# php exec fails even though _www has root privileges

Tags: php, macos, apache, exec, root

I want to open a text file stored on the MAC OS X 10.8 server via php exec command.
To do so, I first created a dummy text file called dummy.txt with some text inside.
Then I created a script file called script.sh including the following:

```
open -a /Applications/TextEdit.app /Library/WebServer/Documents/Secured/upload/dummy.txt
```

and then created a test php file including the following:

```
exec('/Library/WebServer/Documents/Secured/upload/script.sh');
```

The Apache user  "_www" on Mac, was given ownership of all files to _www and group to wheel
permission of dummy.txt and test.php are 644 while permission of the script.sh file is 755.

Logged in as a standard user, running script.sh from the terminal shows the TextEdit program opens the dummy.txt file.

Logged in as root, tried again for standard user as follows:

```
su - myuser -c "/Library/WebServer/Documents/Secured/upload/script.sh"
```

will display editor normally. However;

```
su - _www -c "/Library/WebServer/Documents/Secured/upload/script.sh"
```

cannot run the text editor.

When I access test.php via a client machine browser, it also does not show the text editor.

Accessing through client machine, however, shows the following error in apache error log:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Library/WebServer/Documents/Secured/upload/dummy.txt
```

Adding _www into sudoers file (as below) with ALL permissions did not solve my problems.

```
_www    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I even tried adding the following line into sudoers:

```
Defaults:_www !requiretty
```

and setting shell for _www user from false to sh in passwd file.

None of them worked. I should also add that, security is not my concern at this point. I just want to successfully run it. Then I will take care of the security pitfalls.

Any suggestions ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `open` command (as well as any other way of opening TextEdit) only work in the context of a GUI session; the web server is not part of your session, so it has no way to open something within your session.

There are ways to solve this, but they're really really ugly. They involve switching from the _www user to root (probably with `sudo`), attaching to the context of some process running in the GUI session (`launchctl bsexec somePID somecommand`), then maybe also having to switch to the session owner (`sudo -u loggedinuser`), *then* running the open command.

This is ugly because what you're trying to do is really unnatural. Having something in a web server trigger a GUI edit session really just doesn't make any sense. Please rethink what you're trying to do and why.